# Is there any way to return from explore mode?

Tags: nethack

I tried to apply X (my pickaxe) diagonally up-left. Unfortunately, I wasn't paying close attention. The apply function was skipped (I guess the 7 key corresponds to Yes) so now I'm in Explore mode. I don't know how to exit Explore mode.

The wiki says "Once in, forever in" but it also says something about keeping the old save file when you restore a game. I don't understand what this means.

I want to play this character through, am I screwed? Is that save file a way to return to normal?  If there is a way to get my game back could someone please provide an answer.

I haven't moved since the message "You're now in nonscoring explore mode". Maybe a chance to make bones file, I absorbed 2 bones to get to this point. It would be shame to waste all of that and the time it takes an ARC to get there.

My PC sleeps until I get an answer.

Comment: I swear its like this game has an evil side that just waits for that one mistake...

Comment: It might be possible to edit your saved game to turn off explore mode, but I don’t know how.

Comment: The save files live in the [playground](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Playground), and the code to do the saving lives [here](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Source:NetHack_3.6.0/src/save.c).  Good luck.

Comment: Do you have an existing saved game? Find that and copy it out of the playground that Kevin linked to. What operating system are you using?

Comment: trying to edit save files is a much better way to get "killed by a trickery" than you actually accomplish anything useful.

Comment: I'm playing 343 on windows 10 (online upgrade from 7) , and am not very well-versed in code. So, if it can be done, I'd probably need step by step instruction.   For now, I'll just save it and hope that an answer that I can use comes.

Comment: Explore mode is simply a bitfield in `struct flag`, so I think it might be possible to use a hex editor to edit the save file. I'll post an answer if I can get it working.

Comment: Any thoughts about possible bones?  The wiki says that Explore is "non-scoring," but makes no mention of what happens to bones.  I'm pretty sure the answer is "No," otherwise that would be a huge bug.

Comment: The more I think about this (capital X is not that hard to do accidentally, the warning isn't any more explicit than any other message, albeit the accidental "yes" was kind of a ne-off fluke of inattention) , the more I wonder, "Why would such an obviously undesirable effect be so easy to access?"  Even trying to kick something takes ctrl+d, while other less dangerous actions require a #___.  I hope this trap gets addressed in future versions.

Comment: In the old days, I might try killing the process and using the `recover` program.  Though I'm not seeing a pre-built copy of `recover` for 3.6.0 on nethack.org .  If memory serves me, nethack.exe might look for abandoned working files on startup and do an auto-recover.  It's not like you've got anything to loose at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Sorry, can't be done. Entering both eXplore mode and Wizard mode is permanent.

The mention of the save file is because normally, when you restore a saved game, the save file is deleted so you can't retry and retry (normal for Roguelikes); in Wizard and eXplore mode, you can keep it. This is because those modes are meant, explicitly, for investigating the way the game works, not for playing it, so having a fixed starting point for examining several strategies is useful. But your eXplore status is saved within the save file, so even if you save now and later restore that file, you're still in eXplore mode. And crucially, by now, your previous, *non*-eXplore save file is lost, so you can't go back to it.